# VBScript to find # of folders and files (and subfolders!)

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

I've followed some other posts to write a vbscript that'll count/list/move/whatever all the folders or files in a directory and I have something working but it has 2 limitations.

1) It doesn't return the right number (at least not what matches windows explorer).  I.E., I search my C:\ and it returns 433 folders when windows explore stays there's +10,000 (and a subfolder, C:\Windows, returns 2,234)!

2) I have permissions errors when access folders in various locations even though I run the script as an administrator.

Here's a simple code, that as I test smaller folders, even with many sub folders, it will work:

```
    [Option Explicit
'on error resume next

Dim objFolder, objFSO, objSubFolder, iFolders
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

iFolders = 0

Call CountFolders("C:\Windows")

Sub CountFolders(strPath)
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
                iFolders = iFolders + 1
                If Right(iFolders, 2) = "00" Then
                    IF MsgBox(iFolders & " folders found so far.", VBOKCancel) = 2 Then
                        Wscript.quit
                    End If
                End If
                Call CountFolders(objSubFolder.Path)
        Next
End Sub

msgbox(iFolders)]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DoOi.jpg)
Am I just pushing the limit of what the file system object can do without running into other issues?

Thanks

Comment: I should have clarified, it returns either the correct number or less ( it misses some ) and only seems to do this if there is a very large folder structure, like my entire C:\ or the windows directory.  Also, it does this without error.

Answer (score 0):

Does it *have* to be VBScript? Microsoft has left VBScript behind and any new scripting should be done with PowerShell.

In PowerShell:

```
$everything = get-childitem -path c:\ -recurse -force;
$Foldercount = $everything|where-object{$_.psiscontainer}|measure-object |select-object -ExpandProperty count;
$Filecount = $everything|where-object{-not $_.psiscontainer}|measure-object |select-object -ExpandProperty count;

write-output "$Foldercount folders";
write-output "$Filecount files";
```

What this does:

- Collect everything on the C drive
- Count how many items are folders
- Count how many items are *not* folder
- Print the results

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be and I'll probably abondon VBScript to make it work, but the idea was I had some existing scripts that would have adapted well if this worked instead of starting from scratch.  Maybe it's time to get up to speed, I'll give the power shell option a try.

Comment: I tried the powershell and it worked much better (found 33,000 folders instead of 433, which is actually more than what windows explorer found), but it still had a lot of errors that were persmission denied to folders that an administrator should have access to.  I ran the script file from an administrator command line, if that matters.